# How to show just one (e.g. the first) error message to a form field with Zend framework where validation has failed?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Is there any way to do that with a decorator or do I need to dig deeper into ZF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple validators attached to one form element and want only the first error message to pop up, you can set `breakChainOnFailure` option to TRUE for each validator. In this case, if one of the validators fails, all the subsequent validators are skipped.

```
$element->addValidator(
             new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array('min' => 6, 'max' => 12)),
             true)
        ->addValidator(new Zend_Validate_Alnum());
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the switch I was looking for.

Comment: Note that this method will still allow multiple error messages to be returned from one validator (e.g. the email validator, which can return up to 3 errors at once)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this. My personal favorite is to extend the validator you want to use to only return one custom message. For the email validator this is especially helpful since it shows some crazy error messages that you may not want to show anyway. You can see this method here: http://clintberry.com/2010/07/zend-form-email-validator-customizing-error-messages/

Comment: Interesting to know but for now I'll go with Vika's solution.

Answer (score 0):

if $foo is in an instance of Zend_Form and there is an form element username inside this form then 
`$foo->username->getMessages() ;`  will return array of errors messages to show only one you simply need to do `array_pop($foo->username->getMessages());` . Basically zend decorators uses error view helper to display the messages . You need to extend the default decorator and remove the view helper simply by `echo`

Comment: Another solution which might work, thanks! But as Vika's fits my current needs I prefer that so far.